# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' php What's wrong

Tags: php

```
<?php error_reporting (0); $n = $_GET ['n']; $base = "bob","bob2"; if ($n=$base){ echo "<h1>in the the base</h1>"; } else { echo "<h1>not in base!</h1>"; } ?>
```

I'm trying to get two entries name with 1 variable name
I get the message
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','
What actually not done right
Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: are you planning to write the whole app in a single line?

Answer (score 1):

`$base = "bob","bob2";`

is incorrect syntax.  You either meant

`$base = "bob, bob2";`

for a string of `bob, bob2` or

`$base = "bob"."bob2";` for a string of `bobbob2`.  If you were getting **php** confused with another code language, you probably meant to create an **array,** which would be

```
$base = array(
    "bob" => "bob",
    "bob2" => "bob2",
);
```

in **php,** which could also be better written as

$base = array(
    "bob",
    "bob2",
);

*[Click here to see the outputs.](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/1wd-uxt)*

---

As I see it, the problem is your own **php** knowledge.  Not to sound rude, but it would help to have read some basic books or to look online to see the function of a comma in **php.**  Also, the error *tells* you the error.  There was an unexpected comma!

Answer (score 0):

you need to correct $base variable.

like `$base = "bob, bob2";`

```
<?php error_reporting (0); $n = $_GET ['n']; $base = "bob, bob2"; 
if ($n=$base){ echo "<h1>in the the base</h1>"; } 
else { echo "<h1>not in base!</h1>"; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
$base = "bob","bob2";
```

In php, it means nothing.

The best way to do what you want is :

```
$n = $_GET['n'];
$base = array("bob", "bob2");
if (in_array($n, $base)) { echo "<h1>in the the base</h1>"; } else { echo "<h1>not in base!</h1>"; }
```

And please, don't use error_reporting(0) !